# Image gallery within a movie clip symbol. CS6, AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I set up a gallery within a movie clip symbol. When the user clicks on the clip on the main stage, I want it to go to frame 2 of the movie clip which is the start of the gallery. Is this even possible?

Here is my code:

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

public class Deftones extends MovieClip{

function Deftones() {

swerve1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragStartS);
swerve1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragEndS);
polt1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragStartS);
polt1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragEndS);
rd1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragStartS);
rd1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragEndS);
gauze1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragStartS);
gauze1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragEndS);
stop1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopMusic);
var sound1:Sound= new Sound();
var sound2:Sound= new Sound();
var sound3:Sound= new Sound();
var sound4:Sound= new Sound();
sound1.load(new URLRequest("music/Swerve_City.mp3"));
sound2.load(new URLRequest("music/Poltergeist.mp3"));
sound3.load(new URLRequest("music/Romantic_Dreams.mp3"));
sound4.load(new URLRequest("music/Gauze.mp3"));

function dragStartS(e:MouseEvent){
    e.currentTarget.startDrag();
}
function dragEndS(e:MouseEvent){
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    if (swerve1.hitTestObject(speaker1)){
            SoundMixer.stopAll();
            sound1.play(0);
            title.text="  Swerve City";
            swerve1.x= 218.30;
            swerve1.y= 135.10;
    }
    else if (polt1.hitTestObject(speaker1)){
            SoundMixer.stopAll();
            sound2.play(0);
            title.text="  Poltergeist";
            polt1.x= 217.55;
            polt1.y= 165.35;
    }
    else if (rd1.hitTestObject(speaker1)){
            SoundMixer.stopAll();
            sound3.play(0);
            title.text="Romantic Dreams";
            rd1.x= 217.55;
            rd1.y= 195.60;
    }
    else if (gauze1.hitTestObject(speaker1)){
            SoundMixer.stopAll();
            sound4.play(0);
            title.text="      Gauze";
            gauze1.x= 217.55;
            gauze1.y= 225.85;
    }
}
function stopMusic(e:MouseEvent){
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
    }
}
function photoGallery(){
    photos1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGallery);
    photos1.next1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextPhoto);
    photos1.prev1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, prevPhoto);

    function startGallery(e:MouseEvent){
        photos1.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    function nextPhoto(e:MouseEvent){
        photos1.nextFrame();
    }
    function prevPhoto(e:MouseEvent){
        photos1.prevFrame();
    }
}
```

}
}

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your code already going to frame 2?
`photos1.gotoAndPlay(2);`

Comment: No. See, I have text "Band Photos" that is the movieclip. When the user clicks on that on the main stage, I want the 2nd frame of the movieclip to display over the stage. The second frame is where the gallery starts. I may be going about this all wrong. The above is just the code for the gallery part of it. Would it be helpful to have the whole code?

Comment: I think that would be a good idea. I'm still not entirely sure what you mean though.

Comment: Edited my code so it's all there. So yeah, the movieclip should basically serve as a link that opens and starts my gallery. I'm thinking that what I'm trying to do isn't possible.

Comment: Basically, I have to use nextFrame() somewhere in this project. I was gonna just add a gallery to accomplish this. If what I'm trying to do is wrong, any suggestions would be appreciated. Falling asleep so I'll check back in the morning. Thanks for replying though!

Comment: Can you tell me what output you're getting at the moment? Some screenshots would be handy.

Comment: Tried to post a screenshot, but it says I need a rep. of 10, which I don't have yet. For output, I get no error messages, but nothing happens when you click on the link/movieclip. Otherwise, everything else works fine.

Comment: Could there possibly be any objects on top of it?

Comment: I got it figured out. I had to put everything into a movieclip and place it all on the first frame of the main timeline. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: For future reference, you should have said that when you click the text, nothing happens in the original question. I had no idea what the problem was until you said that. Good luck